# How to write a query that will return the count of objects in table 2 that have a certain field matching table 1's ID in MongoDB Atlas?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-compass

I have two tables, Users and Rides.

I want to return the first and last name of all Users that have 0 rides in the Rides table.

A **User** object is set up with the following fields:

```
_id:
StravaConnect:Object {
  AthleteID: 123
}
FirstName:
LastName:
```

A **Ride** object is set up with the following fields:

```
_id:
AthleteID: 123
Length:
```

How can I aggregate this data to show a list of all users where there are 0 rides where Ride.AthleteID == User.StravaConnect.AthleteID?

Note: I am using MongoDB Compass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this pipeline:

1. [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to get users' rides
2. [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) documents where [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/#mongodb-expression-exp.-size) of `rides` array if greater than 0
3. [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) required fields

```
[
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "rides",
      "localField": "StravaConnect.AthleteID",
      "foreignField": "AthleteID",
      "as": "rides"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      $expr: {
        "$gt": [
          {
            "$size": "$rides"
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "FirstName": 1,
      "LastName": 1
    }
  }
]
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_aUeFR2J3Z7)